# change the formula in a string format into a real formula in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table `validationmaster` with a column called `vrformula`. It contains a formula like:

> pf > 1

In that pf is one of the column names in the datasource table. I have to check whether pf of all the entries in the datasourse table  is > 1 or not, but I don't know how to make it work.

I can fetch that formula correctly but Sql Server considers that formula as a string, I don't know how to change that whole expression into a formula.

For example: `select * from datasource where meterid=4716 and pf>=1` is the statement I want to execute, with that formula at the end of the where clause being generated from the `vrformula` column.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably obvious, nevertheless, a quick and dirty solution is to execute a SELECT for retrieving the column value, then executing a second SELECT containing the condition.

Here I assume that you are executing the SQL statements from a code written in a programming language (not SQL).